# A geometric sequence in an arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

> The sequence a₁, a₂, a₃, ... is an arithmetic sequence with common difference d>0. The term a₆, a₁₀, and a₁₇ form a geometric sequence. If a₁ = 1, find the sum of first 2022 terms in a sequence?

What I have tried: I have tried to make many sequences with numbers (trial and error), but after many failed attempts, not a single sequence fit the restrictions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $a_n=1+(n-1)d$ and $(1+5d)(1+16d)=(1+9d)^{2}$. Expand the square . You can determine the exact value of $d$ from this so you know what $a_n$ is.